# How would you make a Button display a Menu when clicked?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am looking for some code to make a Menu appear next to a button when it is clicked. 
What code would I need for this?

Sorry if this sounds a bit vague.

Comment: Nat: I'm going to guess Cocoa, in Objective-C. (Tags…)

Comment: You should add that to the title to attract answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use NSPopUpButton?

Comment: How would I make the Pop up button not show the arrows at the end and look like a normal button with an image inside?

Comment: Sorted out it not showing arrows and look like a normal button but how do I it show as a image instead of text?

Comment: Why do you want to hide that it's a pop-up? How is the user supposed to know that clicking it will pop up a menu?

Comment: Don't worry I've sorted out what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

NSPopupButton was my first thought as well. It's how apps with the "action gear" buttons accomplish their menus.

If you do have something else in mind though, look at NSMenu's `+popUpContextMenu:withEvent:forView:`. Just hook an action method up to your button, create an NSMenu and populate it with NSMenuItems, and send it to this method along the the current event from NSApplication's `currentEvent` getter.

Comment: How would you control the details of the menu location with that approach?

Comment: You'd want to pass it an NSEvent with the appropriate location as the event's -locationInWindow

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to roll this yourself, rather than using one of the built-in controls that shows a menu, you can create an NSPopupButtonCell and use that to show the NSMenu:

```
NSPopUpButtonCell *popupCell = [[NSPopUpButtonCell alloc] initTextCell:@"" pullsDown:YES];
[popupCell setMenu:yourMenu];
[popupCell trackMouse:event inRect:[yourButton bounds] ofView:yourButton untilMouseUp:YES];
[popupCell release];
```

You'd want to adjust the pullsDown:, inRect:, and ofView: arguments as necessary to position the menu the way you want.

Comment: I wouldn't reuse a popup button cell just for a menu, especially when you can cal `popUpContextMenu`.

Comment: I wasn't aware that the popUpContextMenu methods allowed for precise control of menu positioning (including things like handling being near the edge of the screen correctly by repositioning relative to a different edge of the view).